# Optimization question: Creating a Symfony "live" page (memcached)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, symfony1, memcached

Using: Symfony 1.4.13 (Propel ORM)

I am currently busy optimizing for traffic and I want to relieve the database of getting too many of the same calls.

The "live" page is an overview of articles. Every five seconds an ajax call is made to check for new articles. It works fine at the moment. But I want just one call every 5 seconds (cron job), not 100 calls when 100 users are on the same page at once.

Of course I can do it the old fashion way of just generating an XML document (or something similar) every 5 seconds and load/read that, but I was wondering if you can do it with Memcached too. I'm pretty new to it, so any advice is appreciated. Is it possible to save objects and be accessible to all users? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create caches in two stages: You could create a query cache for Doctrine, but then you would still hit that cache for each request.

You can also use the (view) cache system in Symfony, for which you can use different 'stores', like APC and memcached. You can configure these cache providers any way you want. (So, in your case, set it's lifetime to 5 seconds).

You can read more about the Symfony cache system in the [Jobeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/21).

Comment: Thank you for you anwser, I was considering using view cache, because I am just calling an action with ajax. What stopped me from choosing it at that moment was that I didn't want the users to generate the cache. I do think it's the best option so far.

Comment: What you could try to do is set the lifetime to, say, 15 minutes. Then create a cron job that refreshes the info in your cache backend that runs every 5 minutes. (Maybe even call the same URL, but with a `ignore_cache` kind of parameter).